# Passing array vb.net to vc++ managed DLL

Tags: vb.net, visual-c++, dll

I want to pass a one dimensional array vb.net to vc++ managed DLL,in visual studio 2008.Dll is created.In VB.net, During building time it's give one error.

//ERROR

```
error BC30657: 'abc' has a return type that is not supported or parameter 
type that are not supported .
```

//My Dll code
    // MyCDll.h

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;
#include "stdafx.h"

namespace MyCDll
{       
    public ref class Class1
    {
            public:
                static int abc(int nu[])
            {
               int i,value=0;

               for (i=1;i<5;i++)
               {    
                  if(nu[i])
                  {
                      value=i+1;

                  }
               }
               //Return the position of the number in the array.
               return value;                   
            }           
    };
}
```

The vb.net code:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Module Module1
    'Dim result As Integer

    Sub Main()
              Dim nums() As Integer = New Integer() {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
              'Dim nums() As Integer =  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
         Dim obj As New MyCDll.Class1


         Console.WriteLine(obj.abc(ByVal nums() As Integer)As Integer)

        'result = obj.abc(ByVal nums()As Integer)

       Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in managed C++ need to use the managed syntax.

```
 static int abc(array<int>^ nu)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the dll function correctly. The way you have it coded will give you compilation errors.
You need to pass the parameter (array of integers) like this:

```
obj.abc(nums())
```

This will return a value. Therefore you need to get that value and convert it to string, like below, and then print it:

```
Console.WriteLine(CStr(obj.abc(nums())))
```

Try this

```
        Dim intArray As New List(Of Integer)
        intArray.Add(1)
        intArray.Add(2)
        Dim sResult as string 
       sResult = obj.abc(intArray.ToArray())
```

Comment: Come on, you're a pretty high rep user, this needs at least **some** explanation to avoid going in the low quality posts queue! I'm sure it answers the question, but you can do better than the bare minimum :)

Comment: Thanks for reply. It will not work out still.It's giving same error.Now it's giving another error also after adding <Cstr>.The error is< Number of indices is less than the number of dimensions of the indexed array>. It might have problem during passing the array from vb.net to the dll.

Comment: Hi,I try your code. It can't resolve the problem <'abc' has a return type that is not supported or parameter type that are not supported >.

Comment: pls go through once array caching position ,in my dll code<public:
                static int abc(int nu[])>